# Codeigniter and MYSQL total

Tags: codeigniter

I have a mysql table with results, and would like to add all the subject scores and store the result in another column called 'total' at the end of every student scores. How do I achieve this in codeigniter? Evert subject is a new column. Kindly assist.

Comment: show what you have tried for it?

Comment: I have tried this code.           $total = $this->db->select('SUM(maths) + SUM(eng) + SUM(kisw) as total', FALSE);
   $this->db->update('form_4', $total);
   return;

Comment: Instead of adding your code that you have tried to comment. Update the main post by clicking on edit button.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $this->db->select('SUM(score) as total');
    $q=$this->db->get('results');
    $row=$q->row();
    $score=$row->total;
```

Comment: I have tried it, there seem to be no error but nothing saved in the 'total' column. Please note that the 'total' is in a column. Every student is a new row in the table, and his/her total should appear at the end of their row.

Comment: Please add your table structure.

Comment: My table structure is as follows: id, first_name, last_name, maths, english, kisw, physics, bio, geog, history, agri, business, cre, total, average.

Comment: How do I add all the values in the cells and insert the total in the total column? Please assist.

Comment: There was a simpler way to do this. Your answer helped me figure it out though. This has helped a big deal. Thank you so so much...

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT sum(`maths`) + sum(`eng`) +sum('physics') as total FROM `tablename` 

   $this->db->select('sum(`maths`) + sum(`eng`) +sum(`physics`) as total',false);
   $query=$this->db->get('table');
   return $query->result();
```

Try like this